# Query entire mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a database in mysql, which consists of a few hundred tables (user1,user2,user3..) and
each table has the exact same columns. the two specific columns that i am interested in are the 'body' and 'date created'.

What i would like to be able to do is to query all the tables simultaneously for any entry that has a 'date created'  value between '2013-08-09' and '2013-08-15' while also presenting me with the equivalent 'body' field.

Currently, I run the following query that brings me back the results only for a single table:

```
select * 
FROM user1 
where datecreated between '2001-09-09' and '2001-09-15'
```

and this gives me the 'body' and the 'date created'.

Any ideas?

Comment: `a few hundred tables (user1,user2,user3..) ` this should not happen

Comment: looping with a script and/or creating `UNION` blocks, care for `max_allowed_packet` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to construct a script that creates a temp table, then iterates through all user tables (does MySQL have a way to access the system catalog ?), and  then, for each iteration, run a select on that table, and insert data into the temp table for each select executed in the iteration, then output the contents of the temp table.

But I would be errant if I did not suggest, ***strongly***, that you put all this data from all these tables into a single table with a userId column to distinguish which user each row is for.  Your database schema design is *very very* wrong.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.let me say that im a complete amateur at DB's. what i have done to be more precise it taken multiple outlook pst files and exported them into mysql using already available code.for each .pst there is a unique table that has columns that represent each field in an email (from,to,date,body). so while your answer is very helpful, i really dont know how to implement what you suggested. i am however open to more suggestions.?.

Comment: Because your table structure is as it is, (and not properly normalized as several others have also suggested), the solution to your problem (outlined above in my answer) is considerably more complex than it would be if your data was properly normalized.  If your data was properly normalized, the answer would be a simple query.

Comment: hello again. i just reread you initial comment, and i have described it wrong. each user has a unique id (which is the primary key) which is the last name, first initial (doej).  i wrote user1, user2 earlier to keep it simple. this does make it better doesnt it?

Comment: Actually, no, not if there is a separate table for each user.  If all the data was in one single table, with a `userId` column to identify which user the row was for, then it would be easy.